# List of Symbols

Tags: symbols, glossaries, glossaries-extra

While I am generating list of symbols successfully, there are some undesired things also happen

1. There is a blank page in between the list of figures and list of symbols while I am not giving any command for it.
2. There appears [symbols,title{List of Symbols}] at the end of the list of symbols
3. How to get the title of the list of symbols in the center of the page

My code is;

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\hyphenation{signifi-cant im-proved tele-communication}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=black}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{fancyhf}{
    \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyhead[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\usepackage{tocloft}

% Center ToC heading
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
% Make \chapter leaders bold
\let\oldcftchapleader\cftchapleader
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\oldcftchapleader}


\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{fig/}{graphs/}}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee,sorting=none,minnames=1]{biblatex}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[automake,symbols,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{symbols}

\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\addbibresource{references.bib}


%custom commands
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathit{#1}}}


% Title Page
\title{MS Thesis}
\author{Salman}
\date{\today --- \currenttime}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{9}

\include{abstract}

\begin{normalsize}

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
%   \ifx\totalfigures
    \listoffigures
%   \fi

\end{normalsize}

%\listoftables
\ifx\totaltables
    \listoftables
\fi

\include{abbreviations}
{\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
\printglossaries[symbols,title={List of Symbols}]}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancyhf}
\begin{normalsize}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap_1}
\include{chap_1}

\chapter{Background Theory and Literature Review}\label{chap_2}
\include{chap_2}

\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\rmfamily}
\printbibliography

{\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
\chapter{sample symbols}}
\include{sym_rough}
\end{normalsize}
\end{document}
```

and the symbols.tex file is

```
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Lower case, boldface and italic letter represents a vector}]{a}{\ensuremath{\textbf{\textit{a}}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Upper case, boldface and italic letter represents a matrix}]{A}{\ensuremath{\textbf{\textit{A}}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={$k^{th}$ user's information sequence}]{sk}{\ensuremath{\textbf{\textit{s}}_{k}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={$t^{th}$ information symbol of $k^{th}$ transmitter}]{skt}{\ensuremath{s_{k}(t)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={$t^{th}$ symbol at the output of the equalizer}]{tildeskt}{\ensuremath{s_{k}(t)}}
```

Comment: Please turn your code into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem by removing all unneccessary code and adding some example entries from `symbols.tex`.

Comment: I have removed most of the irrelevant code and also added symbols.tex

Comment: Regarding 1: This does not occur if I compile your code. Regarding 2: `\printglossary[type=symbols,title={List of Symbols}]`.

Comment: Dear close voters: issue #3 is not yet resolved. Please don't close it

Comment: Is your issue solved? How? If not, can you please make your given code compilable? **We do not have your `\include`d files!**